# How to port gethrtime() in C from Solaris to RHEL

Tags: c, solaris, porting, time.h, systimestamp

I'm porting a C project from Solaris to Linux and recompiling it. In a logger.c, gethrtime() function of sys/time.h doesn't compile for Linux. How can I port it to Linux? Is there a  substitute of this in Linux?

Answer (score 4):

The function you're looking for is [`clock_gettime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime):

```
struct timespec t;
if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t) == -1) {
    perror("clock_gettime for CLOCK_MONOTONIC failed");
} else {
    printf("mono clock timestamp: %ld.%09ld\n", t.tv_sec, t.tv_nsec);
}
```

The `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` argument gets the time from an unspecified starting point.  This differs from `CLOCK_REALTIME` which gets the wall clock time.

On most implementations the resolution will be in nanoseconds, however you can find the exact resolution by calling `clock_getres`:

```
struct timespec t;
if (clock_getres(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t) == -1) {
    perror("clock_getres for CLOCK_MONOTONIC failed");
} else {
    printf("mono clock resolution: %ld.%09ld\n", t.tv_sec, t.tv_nsec);
}
```

Comment: @SwapnilShivhare The `clock_getres` function tells you the resolution the real time clock, not the timer itself.  The output is telling you that one tick is 1 ns.  You need to call `clock_gettime` to get the time.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've had around for 10+ years:

Header file:

```
#ifdef __linux
typedef uint64_t hrtime_t;
hrtime_t gethrtime( void );
#endif
```

Source code:

```
#ifdef __linux

hrtime_t gethrtime( void )
{
    struct timespec ts;
    hrtime_t result;

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_HR
    clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC_HR, &ts );
#else
    clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts );
#endif

    result = 1000000000LL * ( hrtime_t ) ts.tv_sec;
    result += ts.tv_nsec;

    return( result );
}

#endif
```

It probably should have some error checking, but since `gethrtime()` doesn't have any way to return an error, I didn't see any reason to add it here.

Answer (score 1):

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). You probably want to use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html).